# print time in double decimal shell script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

how can I print output in double decimal.

below command will print hour in GMT format but i want output as 06 and for double digit hour it should be 10,11,12.

```
date -u  --date="today" +"%I" | awk -F' ' '{print $1-1}'
6
```

Comment: so desired output is `01,02,03...` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `printf "%02d"` in `awk` to achieve it,

```
$ date -u --date="today" +"%I" | awk -F' ' '{printf "%02d\n",$1-1}'
06
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is superfluous here. You can use a relative time format with `date`:

```
date -u --date="-1 hour" +"%I"
06
```

Comment: Wow, brilliant solution.

Comment: Would that be ... Bell Labs?  :)

Comment: Sure, looks like. :) However, I doubt the relative timeformats where available in that version. POSIX doesn't even specify `-d`. Just looked tat up. The GNU version has been written by David MacKenzie

Comment: Btw, I would basically vote for the `awk` `printf` solution which you both showed, but I'm concerned about the daylight saving time issue.

Comment: Oh! just realized it's UTC. No daylight saving time in UTC!!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want:

```
date -u --date="- 1 hour" +"%I"`
```

If the time adjustment is part of your date string, the format will not be munged.

Alternately, if what you really want is a way to zero-pad a number in bash or awk, you have a variety of alternatives:

```
date -u --date="- 1 hour" +"%I" | awk '{printf "%02d\n",$1-1}'
```

Or in bash alone:

```
read hour < <( date -u --date="- 1 hour" +"%I" )
printf '%02d\n' "$hour"
```

Get the idea? Output format happens when you print your output, and `printf` in whatever language formats your output.